# How do I design the user interface in Visual Studio for a Xamarin application with a Windows computer?

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to create an application in Visual Studio. However, I cannot access the user interface of the application when I create the app through the cross platform blank app xamarin.forms.shared.

When I create the app through cross platform blank app native portable, I see the storyboard for the iOS app, but I cannot access it since my computer runs Windows.

Furthermore, I cannot access the Windows implementation of the application. How can I access the user interface while allowing an implementation of all three versions of the app on my Windows computer?

Comment: You must first learn what is Xamarin.Forms and how it is different from native iOS and Android UI. Xamarin currently have visual designers for native iOS and Android, while they are working with Visual Studio team to complete a visual designer for Xamarin.Forms (check out their Previewer announcement at Evolve 2016).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have access to a Mac as a build host. I use a networked Mac Mini to do this. Xamarin explains how to do it pretty well here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: I can't access the Android UI either?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you're trying to use storyboard for iOS app creation and the Android UI for an Android app creation while working within the Xamarin.Forms framework?

Comment: I think so. I'm not entirely sure how Xamarin forms works. I assumed that I could create a single UI for all of the platforms. However, I don't know how to do this, so I tried to get the storyboard for the iOS version thinking that the storyboard design would work for android and windows too. I can't do the storyboard for iOS so I thought that I'd be able to make it work through Android UI. Am I not able to do this?

Comment: Ah, okay, gotcha. I'm in a bit of the same boat with regards to being new to Xamarin Forms. You can create cross platform UIs either in XAML or in code. It's your call, but most things I've read suggest using XAML. Here is Xamarin's "Getting Started With XAML" tutorial that will guide you through some exercises.

Comment: Thanks you for the help. I didn't see the link, but I assume that if I take the first link on Google after typing in "getting started with xaml", I'll get there, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one! Good luck.